# How to enable the subheader, but only for the custom extension in typo3 6.x backend?

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

I want the subheader to show up in my extension's content manager (Typo3 6.2.11 CMS backend). I therefore added the following line in ext_tables.php of my custom extension:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('tt_content','header','--linebreak--,subheader;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:subheader_formlabel','after:header');
```

This helped me show subheader in my extension, but it is now also showing in the default content types which is undesired. How can I make it show up only inside my extension without affecting the other settings of default content types? Besides, I still need to rename subheading to something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may override the TCA of tt_content with your own extension, by placing *tt_content.php* in *your_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides* folder with following content:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['subheader']['displayCond'] = [
  'AND' => [
    'FIELD:CType:=:list',
    'FIELD:list_type:=:your_ext_signature',
]
```

Just exchange `your_ext_signature` with real signature, which you can find in DB for your plugin content element.

[Read more](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/6.2/Reference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond) about displayCond

Comment: I'm still a beginner, where exactly should I look to find the "your_ext_signature"?

Comment: @Ren, first look at BE for id of your plugin content element (mouseover the icon of your plugin in 'Web' or 'List' module), then open phpMyAdmin or any other mysql manager and search for entry in tt_content table with that id. Field `list_type` will contain signature of your plugin.

Comment: The list_type in table 'tt_content' for the entry of my extension is blank :( 
Anything else I can check/do?

Answer (score 0):

With those instruction from @Viktor and some of my hit-and-trials, I arrived at the following solution that worked for me:

In `my_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`, I now have:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['subheader']['displayCond'] = [
    'AND' => [
        'FIELD:CType:=:my_ext_signature',
]];
```

I found my `my_ext_signature` inside the corresponding `CType` field of the table `tt_content`; so I used that for the above displayCond (my `list_type` however was empty so I did not make use of that).

Besides, I was able to rename **subheading** in the backend by adding the following in Resources property of Page: `(Page > Right click globe icon > Edit from the menu > Resources)`:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    subheader.label = My custom title that shows in backend form
}
```

I had to re-install the extension and clear my cache to see the final results.